# Where does msdeploy get it's app_offline from?

Tags: asp.net, iis, msdeploy, webdeploy, app-offline.htm

So I've been having issues with a large website trying to build itself over and over during publishing, being lazy I wanted to take it offline and back on again with publishing.

I followed these instructions:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/30/web-publishing-updates-for-app-offline-and-usechecksum.aspx

```
<EnableMSDeployAppOffline>true</EnableMSDeployAppOffline>
```

Trouble is the page it creates is empty. The title says Site under Construction. but nothing on page, the body has mention of being IE friendly:

> additional hidden content so that IE Friendly Errors don't prevent this message from displaying (note: it will show a 'friendly' 404 error if the content isn't of a certain size).

but thats in a comment, the page is just white blank.

I found this article: [Custom app_offline.htm file during publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846097/custom-app-offline-htm-file-during-publish)

Suggesting that C:\Users[user]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\app_offline.htm has the content for MSDeploy, I'm using VS2013 and went to the 12 folder accordingly, found the file edited it and MSDeploy just laughs in the face of my hopes and smashes my dreams of any sort of on-screen message.

I don't care if all my websites get the same screen, it's an intranet and all my websites look similar anyway, but I just need to get an onscreen message and a meta tag to refresh the page in 1 minute.

Does anyone know where or what to edit?

Comment: You just create an html page called `app_offline.htm` and place it on the root of your site. That's all.

Comment: That will take the site offline permanently. I only want it offline during publishing.

Comment: To add to the confusion, something has re-wriiten the file C:\Users[user]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\app_offline.htm. Still not using it but my changes have been replaced.

Comment: Yes I understand what you say... I just have that file there and rename it this or that... and take it offline while I am making the publishing... of course I make it manually... I understand that you look the automatically way, to find how the default file is written and created.... so to change it this default file...

Comment: There's a new answer that looks like what you need - http://stackoverflow.com/a/38235912/26226

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom app\_offline.htm file during publish](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846097/custom-app-offline-htm-file-during-publish)