# How to change default Site Under Construction page on Azure Web App

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

When I publish my site to Azure web app I see a blank site with title 'Site Under Construction', how can I change that default page

Comment: Has anyone figured this out yet?

Comment: As of March 2019, it appears this is not possible yet. Here's [an old issue at GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/3425) and here's [a newer issue with workarounds](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/6692).

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Custom app\_offline.htm file during publish](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2846097/2999220) - I know this question mentions Azure and the other is about general publishing, but the answers there answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

In Azure Web Apps, the default document is the web page that is displayed at the root URL for a website. The first matching file in the list is used. Refer [File structure on azure](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/File-structure-on-azure) to know more about the files and directories on Azure Web App.
You can add a default document in the default documents list.

Go to Web App -> Settings -> Application settings -> Default documents -> Add and save

You may also check whether the deployed files are available or not using [Kudu Console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can also edit the standard placeholder file, simply log to your Web App using an FTP client like FileZilla, download and edit the **hostingstart.html** file located in the **site/wwwroot** folder.